# default background of grid cell

Tags: vb6

Using flexgrid

I want to check the flex grid cell default color...

If background color is cyan then the below code is working, if background color is white then the below code is not working.

Code (Method1)

```
Private Sub flex1_LeaveCell()
    With flex1
        If .CellBackColor = vbCyan Then
            .TextMatrix(.row, 34) = Val(.TextMatrix(.row, .Col)) 
        ElseIf .CellBackColor = vbWhite Then
            .TextMatrix(.row, 33) = Val(.TextMatrix(.row, .Col)) 
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Code (Method2)

```
Private Sub flex1_LeaveCell()
    With flex1
        If .CellBackColor = vbCyan Then
            .TextMatrix(.row, 34) = Val(.TextMatrix(.row, .Col)) 
        Else
            .TextMatrix(.row, 33) = Val(.TextMatrix(.row, .Col)) 
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Above code is working only for color cyan, the above code is not recongnizing white.

So what is the default bacground cell colour of flex grid.

Need Help

Comment: The second sub (Method2) will not work at all, there is a syntax error  in it. Did you mean to write 'Else'?

Comment: @Abbas, Sorry typing mistake. Now i changed...

Comment: The code's very straight forward, I don't see anything wrong with it. Print the colour with MsgBox flex1.CellBackColor just to be sure.

Comment: @Abbas, I trid with msgbox, it shows as "0", then i used .Cellbackcolor = "0" then it is also not working....

Comment: If .Cellbackcolor = 0 then vbCyan shouldn't work either. Please update the code in your question, show were you added the message box and ad the output in comments. I would also suggest that you remove the redundant code (Method2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me. This isn't working for you?

```
Private Sub flex1_LeaveCell()
    With flex1
        If .CellBackColor = vbCyan Then
            MsgBox "cyan"
        ElseIf .CellBackColor = vbWhite Or .CellBackColor = 0 Then
            MsgBox "white"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```